# Laravel relationship with single column

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have a table called "fields":

```
Schema::create('fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string("label");
    $table->string("name")->unique();
    $table->text("options")->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I want to have another table which simply stores the ids of some of the fields. I will call this `default_fields`.

I basically want a relationship or logic that allows me to grab these `default_fields` like I would with any other relation:

```
Schema::create('default_fields', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer("field_id");
});
```

How can I create a relationship that grabs all the fields whose id's are present in this table? I also want to be able to `sync()`.

Would I just make a model for `DefaultField` and then do something like `Field::whereIn('id', DefaultField::get()->pluck('id'))`?

And then code my own `sync()` logic? Is there a super easy way to do this that I'm missing? I'd also like to be able to sort this like I would any other relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, more productive will be 'is_default' boolean property in the fields table.

Comment: I need this to work like a relationship because the `default_fields` will also be sortable based on their `id` order.

Comment: For example, you can add sort_default_number. In your case normalization is overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a model `Field` that has this relationship:

```
public function defaultFields()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\DefaultField');
}
```

In you controller, you can fetch the `Field` with his related `DefaultFields` like:

```
$fields = Field::with('defaultFields')->get();
```

You can have a similar method `field` in your `DefaultField` model:

```
public function field()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Field');
}
```

In you controller, you can fetch the `DefaultField` with his parent `Field`:

```
$defaultFields = DefaultField::with('field')->get();
```

Comment: Wouldn't in his case be better to use $fields = Field::whereHas('defaultFields')->get(); ? That's how I understand his case? kjdion84?